# Why does a force displace matter?

Tags: forces, displacement

Why does a force displace matter? Is the fact that a force displaces matter purely empirically or do we have a better explanation?

Comment: My understanding was that a force was a specific manifestation of energy but that understanding could be flawed. Made appropriate changes to question.

Comment: Ok but the question doesn't make the assumption that a force is the only source of displacement.

Comment: Never mind, i see what you are saying.

Comment: In order to make a proof, you have to start with axioms that you treat as self-evident. So before Newton could prove things he set out his three laws, for which there was no proof. The second law we call F=ma. What it means is - force and acceleration are just different names for the same thing, scaled by mass. So if there is acceleration, there is force, period. They are the same thing. Force is just a name we give for a mass undergoing acceleration.

Comment: I definitely don’t agree that force and acceleration are just different names for the same thing. However, the simple answer to your question is that force causes acceleration.

Comment: Because it's defined this way.

Answer (score 2):

if the matter is free to move, the application of a force to it will result in an acceleration of that chunk of matter, in proportion to it as set out in newton's law.

Newton's discovery was rooted in experience, but if we imagine that it was false, then (mass x acceleration) could be equal to anything at any time- objects could be set in motion at any velocity without any cause i.e., in the absence of forces. Such a world would hence contain random causality- magic, if you will- which ours doesn't (despite our tendency to wish or hope otherwise).

Is there a deeper explanation for F = ma? Well, from it you can obtain the concept of energy as stored work, and then uncover the mathematical fact that because F = ma has no time dependence, energy is conserved. This means that if one were instead to begin with the time-invariance of the laws of mechanics, one could at least in principle work backwards from that and derive F = ma. I invite the experts here to judge the accuracy of this assertion!

Comment: If you start from mathematics and conservation laws, in some sense $F = ma$ is a tautology, since there is necessarily "something" that transfers momentum between particles, and you choose to call it "force". But that doesn't show how that "force" corresponds to anything in your perception of the real world.